# Can MONOTONE WSAT be in solved in polynomial time?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, np-complete, polynomial-time

In the weighted monotone satisfiability problem (MONOTONE WSAT), the input is an n-variable MONOTONE CNF Boolean formula (when there is no a clause with a negated variable) and an integer k, and the problem is to decide whether there exists a satisfying assignment in which at most k of the variables are true. Can MONOTONE WSAT be in solved in polynomial time or is also NP-complete?

Comment: This is answered in: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/prove-np-completeness-of-deciding-satisfiability-of-monotone-boolean-formula and is NP-complete...

Comment: Thanks! As this answers your question, could you consider posting it as an answer and accepting it, so that it is clear to everyone that your question is answered? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is indeed NP-complete.

Actually, the answer for this question is answered in:

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/prove-np-completeness-of-deciding-satisfiability-of-monotone-boolean-formula

Therefore, this question is closed and answered...